# Обособление с помощью тире

Tags: пунктуация, тире

Допустимо ли так обособлять? Я имею в виду то, как я обособил слова "суммы в троеборье" с помощью тире в таком предложении:

**Что касается главного соревновательного показателя – суммы в троеборье – то места рассматриваемых, а также некоторых других, участников приведены ниже; подробные же сведения об этом находятся в протоколе чемпионата: ссылка на протокол.**

Примечание. Мне брат уже говорил, что не нужно обособлять "а также некоторых других". Но именно на этом сайте я нашёл (а я специально искал), что пользователь Софья создала тему о том, что должно существовать правило, разрешающее в некоторых случаях обособлять конструкции с "а также". И я с ней согласен.

Comment: Исправьте: _имею **в в**иду_. См. http://www.gramota.ru/slovari/dic/?lop=x&bts=x&zar=x&ag=x&ab=x&sin=x&lv=x&az=x&pe=x&word=%D0%B2%D0%B2%D0%B8%D0%B4%D1%83

Answer (score 2):

Обособление при помощи двойного тире в вашем примере возможно. См.: "определения, расположенные внутри предложения, могут выделяться с двух сторон знаком тире. Они приобретают значение пояснительно-уточняющих членов предложения..."

> Правила русской орфографии и пунктуации. Полный академический справочник. М., 2009. С. 207.

Что касается вашего второго примера с присоединительным союзом "а также", следует отметить, что такое обособление некорректно.

В справочнике ***"Трудные случаи пунктуации", (Д.Э. Розенталь, Былинский), говорится:*** "Не обособляются также однородные члены, связанные присоединительными союзами ***а, а то и,*** ***а также и т. п.*** или словами ***а следовательно, а значит*** (т. е. ***запятая ставится только перед союзом или перед союзом и после вводного слова и не ставится после присоединяемого однородного члена, стоящего не в конце предложения***)",например: Изучение послевоенного экономического развития Албании, ***а также культурного роста*** страны позволяет сделать вывод о несомненных преимуществах социалистического строя.

Comment: Мне ещё подсказали, что нужна запятая после того места, которое я обособил с помощью тире. Как считаете, это правильная подсказка? (смотрите второй ответ)

Comment: Да, абсолютно верно. Запятая в этом случае отделяет части сложного предложения, в составе которого есть обособленное определение.

Answer (score 2):

> …допустимо ли так обособлять? Я имею в виду то, как я обособил слова
>   "суммы в троеборье".

Нужна запятая перед "то", лишняя запятая после "других". Корректна, по-моему, такая пунктуация:

***Что касается главного соревновательного показателя – суммы в троеборье, – то места рассматриваемых, а также некоторых других участников приведены ниже...***

> …должно существовать правило, разрешающее в некоторых случаях
>   обособлять конструкции с "а также"…

Но ведь пока такого правила-то нет?

Comment: А разве тире не заменяет запятой?

Comment: Не всегда. Здесь каждый знак стоит на своем месте.  Если вам нужно подробнее, могу дать ссылку.

Answer (score 1):

Что касается главного соревновательного показателя – суммы в троеборье, то места рассматриваемых, а также некоторых других участников приведены ниже; подробные же сведения об этом находятся в протоколе чемпионата: ссылка на протокол.

"Суммы в троеборье" - это приложение к определяемому слову "показателя". Так как после приложения нужна запятая, то по правилу второе тире опускается. Правило таково:

Одно тире ставится, если за приложением в соответствии со структурой предложения следует ЗАПЯТАЯ, в этом случае считается, что второе тире «ПОГЛОЩАЕТСЯ» запятой, например:
Проходя вдоль своего вагона – нашего временного жилища, мы увидели в окне знакомую физиономии. 
Стоял чудесный апрельский день – лучшее время в Арктике, и мы отправились на прогулку.

Розенталь:

Второе тире опускается:
1)      если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая, например: Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой – акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки метров;

http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111

Примечание. Одно тире (первое или второе) опускается:

1) если по условиям контекста после обособленного приложения ставится запятая: Если бы он привлёк к решению вопроса свой прибор — весы, то понял бы источник ошибки; Используя специальное устройство для дыхания человека под водой — акваланг, можно погружаться на глубину в десятки метров; Среди актёров передвижной труппы Сергея Эйзенштейна были юноши, впоследствии ставшие известными кинорежиссёрами, — Григорий Александров, Иван Пырьев, а также актёр Максим Штраух (Газ.);

http://orthographia.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=120#pp120

§ 65. Приложения отделяются одиночным тире (второе тире поглощается другим знаком или опускается):

4) если по условиям контекста после приложения стоит запятая: Проходя вдоль своего вагона — нашего временного жилища, увидели мы в окне знакомую физиономию (тире поглощается запятой, отделяющей деепричастный оборот);

Comment: *Правило таково* - есть авторитетный источник этого "правила"? Да и с примерами надо бы повнимательнее. Как минимум вторая фраза - это переделка Бунина, но у него и знаки другие.